# Segmentation, read word image right to left

Tags: matlab, right-to-left, image-segmentation

Segmentation Code:

```
% // Original Code by Soumyadeep Sinha 
% Modified by Ana with several modification //
% Saving each  single segmented character as one file 

function [s] = seg (a)
myFolder = 'D:\1. Thesis FINISH!!!\Data set\trial';
% a = imread ('adv1.png');

% Binarization %
level = graythresh (a);
bw = im2bw (a, level);

% Complement %
b = imcomplement (bw);

% Morphological Operation - Dilation %
% se = strel('rectangle', [1 2]);
% r = imdilate(b, se); 

r=padarray(b,[0 10]);

% % Morphological Operation - Dilation %
se = strel('rectangle', [1 2]);
i = imerode(r, se); 

%VP
verticalProjection = sum(i, 1);
set(gcf, 'Name', 'Segmentation Trial', 'NumberTitle', 'Off') 
subplot(2, 2, 1);imshow(i); 
subplot(2,2,3);
plot(verticalProjection, 'b-');
grid on;
t = verticalProjection;
t(t==0) = inf;
mayukh=min(t)
% 0 where there is background, 1 where there are letters
letterLocations = verticalProjection > mayukh; 
% Find Rising and falling edges
d = diff(letterLocations);
startingColumns = find(d>0);
endingColumns = find(d<0);

% Extract each region
y=1;
for k = 1 : length(startingColumns)
  % Get sub image of just one character...
  subImage = i(:, startingColumns(k):endingColumns(k)); 
   % im = subImage;
   s = subImage;
   % figure, imshow (s);

   % Normalization %
   [p] =  pad (s); 

   % Morphological Operation - Thinning %
   im = bwmorph(p,'thin',Inf);

% Save %
[L,num] = bwlabel(im);
for z= 1 : num
    bw= ismember( L, z);
    % Construct filename for this particular image.
    baseFileName = sprintf('word6a.%d.png', y);
    y=y+1;
    % Prepend the folder to make the full file name.
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    % Do the write to disk.
    imwrite(bw, fullFileName);
    subplot(2,2,4);
    pause(1);
    imshow(bw);
end
% y=y+1;
end;
s = (im);
```

Original image:    [image: word image]

segmentation output:    [image: saved output of segmentation]

I've done a segmentation for isolated character to do OCR. It's running well,
But, I want the output of the segmentation was arranged sequence not left to right, but right to left like how we read arabic word.

If it works,  [image] would be saved as word6.1.png ,  [image] saved as word6.2.png, the rest saved as word6.3.png

I don't know what to do to the code, to make it read the word right to left.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible to flip the input left to right e.g. using `fliplr`, run the algorithm left to right, and then flip again the output?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, the following changes to the `%Save%` section should do the trick:

```
% Save %
[L,num] = bwlabel(im);
for z= 1 : num
    bw= ismember( L, z);
    % Construct filename for this particular image.
    baseFileName = sprintf('word6a.%d.png', num-z+1);  %% <--- just make the numbering start backwards
    y=y+1;
    % Prepend the folder to make the full file name.
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    % Do the write to disk.
    imwrite(bw, fullFileName);
    subplot(2,2,4);
    pause(1);
    imshow(bw);
end
```

Additionally, increments of `y` may not be needed anymore.

Comment: thank you, but, it makes the output just stuck in one file image, the segmented result supposed to be saved in different file images for each segmented character.